# How to configure AWS DynamoDB Camel component

Tags: java, spring-boot, amazon-dynamodb, apache-camel

I am trying to POC accessing DynamoDB via an Apache Camel application. Obviously Dynamo DB will run in AWS but for development purposes we have it running locally as a docker container.

It was very easy to create a Dynamo BD table locally and put some items in there manually. I used for this my intelij Dynamo DB console and all I had to provide was a custom end point `http://localhost:8000` and the Default credential provider chain.

Now at some certain times of the day I would like to trigger a job that will scan the Dynamo DB items and perform some actions on the returned data.

```
from("cron:myCron?schedule=0 */5 * * * *")
        .log("Running myCron scheduler")
        .setHeader(Ddb2Constants.OPERATION, () -> Ddb2Operations.Scan)
        .to("aws2-ddb:myTable")
        .log("Performing some work on items");
```

When I am trying to run my application it fails to start complaining that the security token is expired which makes me think it is trying to go to AWS rather than accessing the local. I was unable to find anything about how would I set this. The camel dynamo db component (https://camel.apache.org/components/3.15.x/aws2-ddb-component.html) is talking about being able to configure the component with a `DynamoDbClient` but this is an interface and its implementation called `DefaultDynamoDbClient` is not public and so is the `DefaultDynamoDbClientBuilder`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you use Spring Boot as Camel runtime, the simplest way in your case is to configure the `DynamoDbClient` used by Camel thanks to options set in the `application.properties` as next:

```
# The value of the access key used by the component aws2-ddb
camel.component.aws2-ddb.accessKey=test
# The value of the secret key used by the component aws2-ddb
camel.component.aws2-ddb.secretKey=test
# The value of the region used by the component aws2-ddb 
camel.component.aws2-ddb.region=us-east-1
# Indicates that the component aws2-ddb should use the new URI endpoint
camel.component.aws2-ddb.override-endpoint=true
# The value of the URI endpoint used by the component aws2-ddb 
camel.component.aws2-ddb.uri-endpoint-override=http://localhost:8000
```

For more details please refer to the documentation of those options:

- [camel.component.aws2-ddb.accessKey](https://camel.apache.org/components/next/aws2-ddb-component.html#_sb_option_camel_component_aws2-ddb_access-key)
- [camel.component.aws2-ddb.secretKey](https://camel.apache.org/components/next/aws2-ddb-component.html#_sb_option_camel_component_aws2-ddb_secret-key)
- [camel.component.aws2-ddb.region](https://camel.apache.org/components/next/aws2-ddb-component.html#_sb_option_camel_component_aws2-ddb_region)
- [camel.component.aws2-ddb.override-endpoint](https://camel.apache.org/components/next/aws2-ddb-component.html#_sb_option_camel_component_aws2-ddb_override-endpoint)
- [camel.component.aws2-ddb.uri-endpoint-override](https://camel.apache.org/components/next/aws2-ddb-component.html#_sb_option_camel_component_aws2-ddb_uri-endpoint-override)

---

For other runtimes, it can be configured programatically as next:

```
Ddb2Component ddb2Component = new Ddb2Component(context);
String accessKey = "test";
String secretKey = "test";
String region = "us-east-1";
String endpoint = "http://localhost:8000";
ddb2Component.getConfiguration().setAmazonDDBClient(
    DynamoDbClient.builder()
        .endpointOverride(URI.create(endpoint))
        .credentialsProvider(
            StaticCredentialsProvider.create(
                AwsBasicCredentials.create(accessKey, secretKey)
            )
        )
        .region(Region.of(region))
        .build()
);
```

Comment: That was very good thanks. I just needed to find the time to test it. Sorry about the delay. A bit disappointed by the not so clear documentation. E.G. I expected the result of my Scan to be a list as a body. It seems just natural. But it proved to be the `CamelAwsDdbItems` header. How would someone know this? Luckily red hat fuse documentation was much clearer:https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_fuse/7.1/html/apache_camel_component_reference/aws-ddb-component